# Cloud foundy spring-boot project encounter redirect loop issue

Tags: https, spring-boot, cloud, cloud-foundry

All,
I create a spring-boot mvc project, and want to limit to https visit, so i configure it like this.

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo123Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo123Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

but when i visit it in the chrome, like https://web.10.10.132.40.xip.io/ . it show redirect loop in the screen.

And i have configure the application.yml like below:

```
server:
  port: 8443
  tomcat:
    remote_ip_header: x-forwarded-for
    protocol_header: X-Forwarded-Proto
```

Can some one to help?

Comment: Your code and config looks okay to my eyes. I have a similar project, except that I'm using a properties file instead of yml, and don't have the port mentioned.

Comment: i change application suffix and remove the port, but it still not work

Comment: Hope your application is reading yml properly. In case of doubt, you can try using a properties file instead, as I did.

Comment: yes, i have try the application.properties still not work, :(

Comment: No idea, then. In case these links would be helpful: http://www.naturalprogrammer.com/pivotal-cloud-foundry-spring-boot-web-applications/  https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts-cloud-foundry-deployment/